# How can I make sure the Oliphaunt in Rome Total War doesn't lag me out?

Tags: rome-total-war

There is a type of elephant in RTW called the Oliphaunt. It is a unit that can only be brought into the game through a cheat. However when I go into the battle to see these beasts in action the game lags and then closes out completely. Is there a way to see the elephants in battle without losing the battle and losing data?

Comment: It would help if you posted some information about your computer spec. I would try and lower the settings and see if it works then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely challenging for most people. The game needs to be updated using a P17-T code which the game gives you in the beginning. After you get the new update you can successfully crush your enemies and watch the fun.

Comment: Nice act, you two, but your histories seem to indicate that you answer each other's questions at an alarming rate... This is called "reputation farming", and is against the rules of the site. Just a warning, but any accounts involved in reputation farming are at risk of deletion.